# Calculate number of perfect squares in a given big range in C

Tags: c

I already have the code where I calculate the number of perfect squares between 1 and a max range:

```
int perfectCounter = 0;
int i = 1;
int maxRange;

scanf("%d", &maxRange);

while (i <= maxRange) {
   float tempSquare = sqrt(i);
   int integerPart = tempSquare;

   if (tempSquare == integerPart)
      perfectCounter++;
}
```

Problem is, that max range must be between 1 and 10^1000, so I can't store that maxRange on a int, long or long double. I can't think on a solution for that, without using external libraries that handle very big numbers.

Comment: And why do you want to calculate the number of perfect squares between 1 and 10^1000?

Comment: you need a quantum workstation there, but to ease the way i advice you to go way round, means square it, dont root it. and when number appears to leave bounds use modulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to **count** how many perfect squares there are between `1..N` all you need to do is: take a square root of `N` and get its integer value :)

Just think about it. For the range `1..10` the correct answer is `3` (`1`, `4`, `9`) which is, incidentally, the rounded-down `sqrt(10)`. If you don't want to count `1` as a perfect square - fine, just don't count it.

And generally, to see how many "perfect squares" are there in range `M..N` all you need to do is:

```
(int)sqrt(N) - (int)sqrt(M) - 1
```

That should be simple enough because all you need to do now is get the square root of a "very-big-number". That you'd have to write a function for, true. But it is not too complicated and there are numerous resources on the Web that can help you with that.

Comment: *Cuius rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.* :)

Answer (score 2):

- The number of perfect squares between any range is done **without bruteforcing**
- In your case , the square root of 10^1000 is 10^(1000/2)=10^500. which means **10^500** perfect squares.
- for any other range, just try to narrow it as much as you can using arithmetics, then use modulo to store reasonable values in int32 registers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use external libraries, I suggest you find a way to store your numbers in an array of `unsigned int`. You would have to write your own arithmetic functions.

Otherwise there is the [The GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score -1):

```
scanf("%d%d",&l,&u);
    x=floor(sqrt(u))-ceil(sqrt(l))+1;
    printf("%d\n",x);
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by adding more information about how this answers OP's question.